# Small modification to regex to make it work?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the 6 or 7 number sequence and put it in the urls array.

```
<a href="/product/view/4539922/" class="raw_clafd">
```

However I am having a problem with the regex below.

```
preg_match_all('/<a\s+href="\.\/view\/(\d{6,7})\/"  class="raw_clafd">/', $str, $urls);
```

What am I missing? Thank you

Comment: See     [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thank you for your comment. However I am finishing this and I am not willing to change my entire code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match `/product` with `\.`

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('#<a\s+href="/product/view/(\d{6,7})/"\s+class="raw_clafd">#', $str, $urls);
```

But I really believe you should consider using DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value after /view/ just by using

```
/\/view\/(\d{6,7})/
```